# Not able to delete kubernetes cluster in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm getting this error when deleting a cluster from GKE.

> **Google Compute Engine: The subnetwork resource 'projects/abc-cluster-abc/regions/us-east1/subnetworks/sub-network-1'
>   is already being used by
>   'projects/abc-cluster-abc/zones/us-east1-d/instances/gke-qa-cluster-pool-1-abc-xyz'**

How to delete it? Please help us out.

Answer (score 0):

First, you’ll need to [delete](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc#deleting_subnets) subnetwork “sub-network-1” as it’s used by node “gke-qa-cluster-pool-1-abc-xyz”.

Then you’ll be able to delete your cluster.

Feel free to share any error message to help you further in the comment section.

Answer (score -1):

You can delete a GKE cluster by 2 simple ways

```
                  1. BY gcloud
                  2. BY Console
```

**1.**

```
            gcloud container clusters delete [CLUSTER_NAME]
```

**2.**
[image]

**--> By choosing the cluster to select your gke cluster and select shutdown to Delete(or)Remove**